# UWP input injection does not work on other UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm using the [UWP input injection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.inputinjector?view=winrt-20348) to simulate keyboard inputs into other applications:

```
var inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
{
    VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.PageDown,
}});
```

This works fine on traditional applications. However, the injection won't work on UWP apps like Drawboard PDF. Interestingly, this behavior does not apply to all keys. For example `VirtualKey.PageDown` and `VirtualKey.Right` won't work, but `VirtualKey.Space` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP input injection does not work on other UWP apps

The problem is you have not specificed <kbd>PageDown</kbd> `KeyOptions`. The default is `None`, and it does not work for UWP app. please set `KeyOptions` as [`ExtendedKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyoptions?view=winrt-20348) (*The key is an extended key, such as a function key or a key on the numeric keypad*), it will work as expect.

```
var inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
{
    VirtualKey = (ushort)VirtualKey.PageDown,
    KeyOptions=InjectedInputKeyOptions.ExtendedKey
}});
await Task.Delay(1000);
```